# Bug in Promotional catalog price rules 1.8.0.0

Tags: magento, catalog, magento-rules

Is there a bug in Magento 1.8.0.0 in the catalog pricing rules. I'm trying to get a data feed with the proper pricing but 1.8.0.0 spits out nothing whilst 1.8.1.0 gives me what I want.

```
$store_id = 1; // Use the default store
$discounted_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice( 
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeTimeStamp($store_id), 
                Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)->getWebsiteId(), 
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(), 
                $_product->getId());

// if the product isn't discounted then default back to the original price
echo $discounted_price;`
```

Unfortunately my development server is on 1.8.1.0 and my live site is running 1.8.0.0 can anyone suggest a fix. I should add the frontend prices and promotional prices are all being shown correctly, so the data is there somewhere, now at a loss as to where to retrieve it from.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Magento CE 1.8.0.0 and was fixed in 1.8.1.0

If you want only the fix instead of upgrading your live site, pls use this fix :

https://bitbucket.org/gferon/magento-1.8-catalogrule-fix/overview

Here's one more fix for applying existing rules on products.

http://www.techytalk.info/catalog-price-rules-not-being-applied-after-product-save-magento-ce-1-8-0-0/

Hope it helps you